# Springboot form validation for ensuring one date does not come before another?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot

After following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/, I want to do form validation that checks if the `dateTo` value comes before the `dateFrom` value. It would be awesome if there were some kind of annotation solution. They are stored as strings in the empty model supplied by my form.

```
@NotNull(message="You must select a date.")
@NotBlank(message="You must select a date.")
private String dateFrom;

@Min(dateFrom)
private String dateTo;
```

Obviously this doesn't work because we can't compare whether one String is smaller than the other... Is there an alternative? The problem is that I want to provide a message in the UI right from the form validation check, just like how I can check if the message is null or blank.

```
    // Create Request
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String saveRequest(Principal principal, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "requestModel") RequestModel requestModel, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    ....
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // log.info("There are binding errors.");
        return "send";
    }
    ....

    // Format given date
    Date dateFrom = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
        dateFrom = formatter.parse(requestModel.getDateFrom());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "send";
    }

    try {
        if (requestModel.getDateTo() != null && !(requestModel.getDateTo().isEmpty())) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
            Date dateTo = formatter.parse(requestModel.getDateTo());

            // Check if dateTo is before dateFrom
            if (!dateTo.before(dateFrom)) {
                // If not (proper case), set the date
                requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateTo);
            } else {
                // Improper case, log error
                //TODO Update UI?
                log.info("dateTo cannot come before dateFrom");
                return "send";
            }

        } else {
            requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateFrom);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "send";
    }
```

I don't want to have to perform the validation in the POST method itself...

**Update:**

```
@AssertTrue(message="The end date cannot come before the initial date.")
private boolean isValid() {
    return !dateTo.before(dateFrom) && this.dateFrom.before(this.dateTo);
}

public Date getDateFrom() {
    return dateFrom;
}

public void setDateFrom(Date dateFrom) {
    this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
}

public Date getDateTo() {
    return dateTo;
}

public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
    this.dateTo = dateTo;
}
```

What about something like the above?

Comment: Are you looking for an annotation that let you specify arbitrary properties to be compared or would a class level annotation (`@ValidDates`) be sufficient?

Comment: I added a possible solution above. I basically want to compare whether the end date is before the initial date right in the Springboot form validation binding.

Comment: Your approach is fine, nice and simple. Is something not working? You can always make a custom annotation with a custom validator if you want to resuse it later. Would probably have to introduce an interface then. Something like `HasFromToDates`

Comment: My only problem is that I want the dates sent in the model to be Strings, and to convert them afterward, so a custom validator would be better because I could parse the Strings as Dates, run the check, then update the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own validator/validation annotation (see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#d0e371 )

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE}) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Constraint(validatedBy=YourDateValidator.class) 
public @interface ValidDates {
    String message() default "{message.id}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class YourDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator< ValidDates, 
    TypeToBeValidated> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidDates constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TypeToBeValidated value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) 
    {
        < validation code, returning true for a valid value >
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@ValidDates
class TypeToBeValidated {
    private String dateFrom;
    private String dateTo;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I'm not sure how to pass both dates into the validator in order to compare them...

Comment: @santafebound `TypeToBeValidated` is your bean containing `fromDate` and `toDate`. It's a type level annotation, you annotate the class with it, not the individual properties.